# win32 - Second call to EM_SETTEXTEX won't properly show the appended text. Why?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to append text to a rich edit control by appending the original string and resending the EM_SETTEXTEX message.

```
char outputText[4096] = "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg0\\deff0{\\colortbl;\\red0\\green0\\blue0;\\red255\\green0\\blue0;\\red50\\green205\\blue50;\\red255\\green140\\blue0;}TEST";

SETTEXTEX s;s.flags = ST_DEFAULT;s.codepage = CP_ACP;
SendMessage(hOutputWndText,EM_SETTEXTMODE,(WPARAM)TM_RICHTEXT,NULL);
SendMessage(hOutputWndText,EM_SETTEXTEX,(WPARAM)&s,(LPARAM)outputText);
```

I know I do not have a closing bracket on the string but it shows what I want.

```
TEST
```

Now I append the string and "re-set" the text inside the rich edit control. Notice, I add a closing bracket just incase.

```
strcat_s(outputText,"NEWSTUFF}");
SendMessage(hOutputWndText,EM_SETTEXTEX,(WPARAM)&s,(LPARAM)outputText);
```

And the output this time.

```
NEWSTUFF}
```

What gives? I printed the variable outputText to the console and I get the complete string.

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg0\deff0{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;\red50\green205\blue50;\red255\green140\blue0;}TESTNEWSTUFF}
```

Comment: Your question is basically: "what happens when I send invalid RTF?".  The answer is: "anything can happen".  If you want a catalog of ways that RTB deals with invalid RTF then you can create one yourself.  But that won't be useful to anybody, the only sane way to deal with this is stop testing unspecified behavior.

Comment: So, it will be "broken" even if I set the text with correct RTF afterwards? I'm guessing the answer to this is yes, even though it is "unspecified", and that explains a lot